# Get latitude and longitude points in Google Maps polyline

Tags: google-maps, overlay, latitude-longitude, polyline

I want to draw `Polyline`s with the Google Maps JavaScript API. Is there a tool that will help me get the latitude and longitude points by just clicking on the map, then exporting an array of lat-long pairs?

I imagine something like the personalized maps service (My Places) in Google Maps where you can click-snap on the roads to specify your own driving directions. I'd like to take that one step further. That is, to export an array of lat-long pairs that specify the roads traveled.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer might be a little late but today I was trying to figure out what I believe to be the same issue as this question. So, you can draw the points on the map then get that encoded polyline with Google's Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility then I recommend using Mapbox polyline utility to convert the overview_polyline to latitude and longitude pairs values. The latitude and longitude pairs are also on Googles Utility but it is a bit of a hassle to continuously copy each coordinate.

For more information about the Mapbox Polyline Utility process:
http://zevross.com/blog/2014/09/23/convert-google-directions-to-geojson-points-or-polylines/

And here is Google's Encoder Utility:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Drawing Tools library:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#drawing_tools
which will give you an encoded polyline. You can use that to draw a line, or you can decode it to get the specific points using the geometry library:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry.html